# AngularJS: How to add ng-idle to my current .config scenario and why i am getting the error of $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My scenario is:

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider)
{
    $routeProvider.when('/home', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html', controller: 'homeCtrl'});
}
```

this is my current `.config()`. How can I integrate the code below with the code above:

```
.config(function(IdleProvider, KeepaliveProvider) {
  IdleProvider.idle(10*60); // 10 minutes idle
  IdleProvider.timeout(30); // after 30 seconds idle, time the user out
  KeepaliveProvider.interval(5*60); // 5 minute keep-alive ping
})
.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('IdleTimeout', function() {
        // end their session and redirect to login
    });
});
```

Another problem is that this `$rootScope` function throws the following error:

```
Error: $http is not a function
$rootScope.synchronization@http://localhost/task-app/js/app.js:53:19
```

and my scenario is:

```
$rootScope.synchronization = function($scope, $rootScope, $http , $location ,$cookies , $interval,  $window) 
{
alert("synchronization in doing!");         //alert of synchronization
if(localStorage.getItem('job_id') !== "" && localStorage.getItem('job_id') > 0)
{
    alert("found job id!");                 //alert job found
    console.log(window.localStorage.getItem('job_id'));             //alert job id
    console.log(window.localStorage.getItem('done_tasks'));
    var done_tasks = [];
    var job_id = [];

    //console.log(done_tasks);

    done_tasks = window.localStorage.getItem('done_tasks');
    job_id = window.localStorage.getItem('job_id');

    alert(done_tasks);

    alert(job_id);

    var userData = $http(
    {
            method: "post",
            url: "http://localhost/mobile-data/update-tasks.php",
            data: {
                    done_tasks : done_tasks,
                    job_id: job_id,
                },
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    });
    userData.success(function (userdataobject)
    {
        //$rootScope.status_id = userdataobject["status_id"];
        //$rootScope.message = userdataobject["message"];
        if( userdataobject["status_id"] == 1)
        {
            alert('im in success function and status id =1');
        }
        if( userdataobject["status_id"] == 0 )
        {
            alert('im in success and status id = 0');
        }

        localStorage.setItem('job_id', '');
        localStorage.setItem('done_tasks', '');

    })
}
};
```

and my call to this function in controller is like this:

```
$interval($rootScope.synchronization(), 2000 , 1, false, $scope, $rootScope, $http , $window);
```

I'm newbie in angularJS. P.S thumbup the question to encourage me to ask questions here.

Comment: Please answer this question...